# Protractor sendKeys() not working Element not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

Hey I am new to automated tests using protractorJS to test a homepage done in angularJS. The code I have written so far has worked the problem is **I cant send keys to the search field** after running the code i get **Message: Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds**

I think something is wrong with my element by syntax:

```
 element(by.css("input[name='search_query']")).sendKeys('Virginia Beach VA');


--- HTML code block ----
<div ng-transclude>
<input parse-search-query="" type="text" tabindex="1" name="search_query" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search by City ST, Zip, or Address" data-ng-model="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchFormController.searchParams.search_query" data-ng-change="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchFormController.clearErrors()" data-focus-on="focusQuery || form.search_query.$error" data-uib-typeahead="suggestion as suggestion.label for suggestion insearchQueryFieldCtrl.getSuggestions($viewValue)" data-typeahead-focus-first="false" data-typeahead-min-length="0" data-typeahead-wait-ms="300" data-typeahead-on-select="searchQueryFieldCtrl.setSearch($item)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-69-6255">
</div>   



---homeshptest.js file ----

    describe('New stack hompage test', function() {
  it('should test search form', function() {

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/');
        browser.sleep(5000); 
        element(by.css("input[name='search_query']")).sendKeys('Virginia Beach VA');
        browser.sleep(5000);



     VA');
```

});
});
    ---------------

Comment: can you post the html code of that element?

Comment: I don't see `ng-app` defined explicitly which makes me think this is a manually bootstrap app. If this is the case, you might be in this situation: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/66.

Comment: This angualrjs code is used at an enterprise level. This is code from a site like apartments.com i am trying to create an automated test for it.

Comment: I simplified my question and details above.

Comment: I would add browser.sleep(10000); after browser.get and I highly recommend changing your css selector it will break the moment you interact with the input field (try element(by.css("input[name='search_query']"))and seperate the .clear() from the .sendKeys() into seperate actions. if you still get synchronization errors you will need to remove angular synchronization.I n theory an Angular app is an angular app but in practice a lot of things can break protractor synchronization.

Comment: I think you mean ng-untouched in your css. I do not know if that would cause the error you are seeing, but it's always good to fix what you do see and see if the problem gets better.

Comment: Also it looks like there is a typo: insearchQueryFieldCtrl needs a space after in?

Comment: Sonhu your solution worked! it found the input element problem now is I cant send key to the input field i get message element not visible. I know you said that you would create 2 separate actions could you give me and example of what you mean?

could it be this: input[name ='search_query'].sendKeys('Virginia Beach VA');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `browser.ignoreSynchronization =true` after your browser.get() statement. it seems your webpage doesn't have angular in it.

Comment: I had your suggestion implemented already. Thanks for you help though.